# Can Debezium Capture Changes of a Postges Materialized View

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We are currently trying to use Debezium for capturing changes of 4 tables in a Postgres database. We are currently aware that for this use case we could use a kafka-streams app to join/aggregate tables for a KTable, however we want to keep kafka-stream topology simple, so the idea would be to use a Materialized View from Postgres and capture it changes.

Is it possible to do this, if so than how should we configure it?

**Kafka Connect Source Configuration:**

```
{
"name": "campaign-db-source-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "campaign-db",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "database.dbname" : "campaigndb",
    "database.server.name": "campaign-db"
  }
 }
```

This config currently can capture all changes from individual tables but not from materialized view. (There is no topic created)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the Debezium Postgres connector cannot capture changes from a view. You'd either have to persist your join in a table and capture that or indeed use something like Kafka Streams to create the join.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We are going with kafka-streams options and will create ktables with it.

Comment: @fgakk And did you get any luck with **Kafka-Streams**? Plus how was your experience with **Kafka-Streams** in terms of handling **influx of data** with multiple instances of Kafka-Streams application?

Comment: @gunnar do **Debezium** have any plans of supporting this requirement?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar we did a PoC and it worked fine at first glance but tbh I was out of the project before it could go live so I cannot say for sure how the experience with a productive environment.