# How to use debezium with views, instead of tables with sql server connect

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have been trying to find a way to use `views` from an `sql server`, to be used in kafka source connect with debezium, but the cdc doesn't allow that.

I also used indexed views, but cdc still doesnt recognize it and asks for a Table.

> Is there a way around this, where I can monitor real-time changes
>   from multiple views using debezium in particular?

Comment: CDC does not work against views. You either need to choose a different path/technology or work directly with the associated tables.

Comment: Maybe you can find this alternative useful, using Hibernate: [Materializing Aggregate Views With Hibernate and Debezium](https://debezium.io/blog/2018/09/20/materializing-aggregate-views-with-hibernate-and-debezium/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Debezium Capture Changes of a Postges Materialized View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58537705/can-debezium-capture-changes-of-a-postges-materialized-view)